# Liberty Profile - getting error in Linux [Cannot start a new UOW. A LocalTransactionContainment is already active with work]

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I'm using the following version of Websphere Liberty Profile in

**Windows**

```
 WebSphere Application Server 19.0.0.6 (1.0.29.cl190620190617-1530) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_211-b12 (en_US)
```

**Linux**

```
WebSphere Application Server 19.0.0.6 (1.0.29.cl190620190617-1530) on IBM J9 VM, version 8.0.5.35 - pwa6480sr5fp35-20190418_01(SR5 FP35) (en_US)
```

When i run service that involves thread, i get the following error in linux whereas i dont get the error in windows,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start a new UOW. A LocalTransactionContainment is already active with work.
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.impl.LTCUOWCallback.uowPreBegin(LTCUOWCallback.java:128) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableLTCUOWCallback.uowPreBegin(EmbeddableLTCUOWCallback.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableLTCUOWCallback.contextChange(EmbeddableLTCUOWCallback.java:66) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.LTCUOWCallbackService.contextChange(LTCUOWCallbackService.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWScopeCallbackManager.notifyCallbacks(UOWScopeCallbackManager.java:66) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.UserTransactionImpl.begin(UserTransactionImpl.java:65) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableUserTransactionImpl.begin(EmbeddableUserTransactionImpl.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.UserTransactionService.begin(UserTransactionService.java:65) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper.begin(UserTransactionWrapper.java:111) ~[com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer_1.0.29.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

The IllegalStateException suggests that transactional work (such as a database operation) was performed previously on the thread, with the work having not been committed or rolled back yet when the UserTransaction.begin operation attempts to start a new transaction.  Please check the application code leading up to this point, and if possible, post it to your question.  There is no reason why the behavior should differ between platform if you are running the same code in both cases.